# validacion de valores en servel eclipse java

Tags: java, eclipse

```
if (nombre!=null || opcion!=null || tipoEdad!=null){
    }if (altura >= 0 || peso >= 0 || cintura >= 0 || abdomen >= 0) {
        
    }
```

Tengo una duda, no si estara bien mi validacion de datos html, en servel?
Se agradece la ayuda

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta.

Comment: tengo campos creados en html como nombre en name=txtNombre, opcion como name = cboOpcion, etc y estoy en servelt eclipse cree variables para almacenar esos valores. nombre, opcion, etc le cree sus variables para almacenar que son nombre, opcion como sale en el codigo que envie;realizar la validacion de campos vacios, no se si el codigo que escribi es correcto? todavia no puedo ejecutar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veamos tu código:

Declaras un if para validar que no haya nulos o en nombre, o en opción o en tipoEdad

Si deseas que esa validación se haga en los tres campos deberías de utilizar "&&"

Pero luego cierras el if con paréntesis de apertura y cierre, por lo que el if siguiente te queda fuera, o sea, son dos if independientes

```
if (nombre!=null || opcion!=null || tipoEdad!=null)
{

}
```

Aquí lo que haces, es que si la altura es mayor o igual a 0, O el peso es mayor o igual a 0, o la cintura es mayor o igual a cero, o el abdomen es mayor o igual a cero, pero que no todos los datos sean mayores o iguales a cero, si no, deberías de emplear &&

```
if (altura >= 0 || peso >= 0 || cintura >= 0 || abdomen >= 0) {
    
}
```

Si lo que deseas es que se cumpla siempre y ambos if sean encadenados, deberían de ser:

```
//Si no hay nulos ni en nombre, ni en opción ni en edad
if ((nombre != null) && (opcion != null) && (tipoEdad != null))
{
    //Si la altura, el peso, la cintura y el abdomen son mayores o iguales a cero
    if ((altura >= 0) && (peso >= 0) && (cintura >= 0) && (abdomen >= 0)) {

    }
}
```

Y si ya deseas informar al usuario, donde tiene algún error o le falta por meter algún dato:

```
//Si no hay nulos ni en nombre, ni en opción ni en edad
if (nombre != null){
    if (opcion != null){
        if (tipoEdad != null){
            //Si la altura, el peso, la cintura y el abdomen son mayores o iguales a cero
            if (altura >= 0){
                if (peso >= 0){
                    if (cintura >= 0){ 
                        if (abdomen >= 0){
                            //Y si se cumplen todos los condicionales, aquí pondrías tu código
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println("La medida del abdomen tiene que ser mayor o igual a cero");
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("La cintura tiene que ser un valor mayor o igual a cero");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("El peso tiene que ser mayor o igual a cero");
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("La altura tiene que ser mayor o igual a cero");
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Tiene que poner el tipo de edad");
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Tiene que escribir una opción");
    }
}
else{
    System.out.println("Tiene que escribir un nombre");
}
```

Hacerlo con if sería algo confuso y enrevesado, pero es para darte una idea

Comment: vale pa, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, saludos !!

Comment: me resulto:)...